# Datatable pagination issue

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have included a jQuery DataTables plugin in my page. It's not working properly. My issue is that even though i have 20 records, it's showing 20 records with no data available. (i.e) `Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries`.

Below is the image of my page

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Most likely you're inserting `tr` nodes after the table has been initialized. Please show how you initialize and populate the table.

Comment: You can see the message No data available in table message too. Your datatable is not properly designed or populated. Post your html code.